# jQuery Spectrum color picker can't disable

Tags: javascript, jquery, spectrumjs

I added the Spectrum color picker to my website because I needed a color picker with opacity, and I have a checkbox to enable/disable which was working with a simple color picker, but here I cannot manage to disable it, even with the property.

I tried with changes to every Spectrum property or only with the disabled one but it doesn't work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#bg_color').spectrum({
    type: "color",
    showPalette: false,
    showPaletteOnly: true,
    togglePaletteOnly: true,
    hideAfterPaletteSelect: true,
    showInput: true,
    disabled: true
  });

  $('#boolean_check_color').change(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
      $("#bg_color").spectrum({
        type: "color",
        hideAfterPaletteSelect: true,
        showInput: true,
        showInitial: true,
        disabled: true
      });
    } else if (!$(this).prop('checked')) {
      $("#bg_color").spectrum({
        type: "color",
        hideAfterPaletteSelect: true,
        showInput: true,
        showInitial: true,
        disabled: false
      });
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/spectrum/1.8.1/spectrum.min.css" integrity="sha512-KuSX+43gVS5MEIJD2ewtrFPOHqC1PJnL8o2f5ciggPC0JUZ8XV0QXlfArO1mSzKkVFdRjsBDfrTU96C5SuRfqQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class='p-2'>
  <label for="bg_color">Background color</label>
  <input id="bg_color" name="bg_color" value='#ffffff'>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic checkbox toggle button group">
    <label for="boolean_check_color">or transparent &nbsp</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check" id="boolean_check_color" autocomplete="off" name="boolean_check_color" checked>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/spectrum/1.8.1/spectrum.min.js" integrity="sha512-1aNp9qKP+hKU/VJwCtYqJP9tdZWbMDN5pEEXXoXT0pTAxZq1HHZhNBR/dtTNSrHO4U1FsFGGILbqG1O9nl8Mdg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [documentation](https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/) for the Spectrum library there are `enable` and `disable` methods you can use to set the state of the control based on the `checked` property of the checkbox. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#bg_color').spectrum({
    type: "color",
    showPalette: false,
    showPaletteOnly: true,
    togglePaletteOnly: true,
    hideAfterPaletteSelect: true,
    showInput: true,
    disabled: true
  });

  $('#boolean_check_color').change(function(e) {
    $("#bg_color").spectrum(e.target.checked ? 'disable' : 'enable');
  })
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/spectrum/1.8.1/spectrum.min.css" integrity="sha512-KuSX+43gVS5MEIJD2ewtrFPOHqC1PJnL8o2f5ciggPC0JUZ8XV0QXlfArO1mSzKkVFdRjsBDfrTU96C5SuRfqQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class='p-2'>
  <label for="bg_color">Background color</label>
  <input id="bg_color" name="bg_color" value='#ffffff'>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic checkbox toggle button group">
    <label for="boolean_check_color">or transparent &nbsp</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check" id="boolean_check_color" autocomplete="off" name="boolean_check_color" checked>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/spectrum/1.8.1/spectrum.min.js" integrity="sha512-1aNp9qKP+hKU/VJwCtYqJP9tdZWbMDN5pEEXXoXT0pTAxZq1HHZhNBR/dtTNSrHO4U1FsFGGILbqG1O9nl8Mdg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks man, it is working. Since my english is not perfect I might pass throught some informations. I have a question here: is the e argument passed in function the checkbox tag ? So you target the checked attribute ?

Comment: `is the e argument passed in function the checkbox tag` it's the Event object that's raised. The `target` property is a reference to the element which raised the event - in this case the checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version. Took some time to figure out the correct method due to some [unsolved issues](https://github.com/bgrins/spectrum/issues/520)

but they were irrelevant compared to the [manual](https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/#methods)

I suggest you test the checked state of the checkbox at load

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const $chk = $('#boolean_check_color');
  const $bg  = $("#bg_color");
  const dis = $chk.prop("checked") 
  const setState = disable => $bg.spectrum(disable ? "disable" : "enable");
 
  $('#bg_color').spectrum({
    type: "color",
    showPalette: false,
    showPaletteOnly: true,
    togglePaletteOnly: true,
    hideAfterPaletteSelect: true,
    showInput: true,
  });
  setState(dis)
  $chk.on("click", function() {
     setState(this.checked)
  })
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/spectrum/1.8.1/spectrum.min.css" integrity="sha512-KuSX+43gVS5MEIJD2ewtrFPOHqC1PJnL8o2f5ciggPC0JUZ8XV0QXlfArO1mSzKkVFdRjsBDfrTU96C5SuRfqQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class='p-2'>
  <label for="bg_color">Background color</label>
  <input id="bg_color" name="bg_color" value='#ffffff'>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic checkbox toggle button group">
    <label for="boolean_check_color">or transparent &nbsp</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check" id="boolean_check_color" autocomplete="off" name="boolean_check_color" checked>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/spectrum/1.8.1/spectrum.min.js" integrity="sha512-1aNp9qKP+hKU/VJwCtYqJP9tdZWbMDN5pEEXXoXT0pTAxZq1HHZhNBR/dtTNSrHO4U1FsFGGILbqG1O9nl8Mdg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: OK so it's safer with this method is it ? 


By the way, when I'm changing the color with the picker, the case where my color is supposed to show keep to white color. Do I have to link the value attribute of the tag somewhere or it is anything else.

Comment: I do not know what you mean. Please add some code to show what you mean

Comment: Look in you're code snippet, when I change color from the picker, the little square stay white for any reason.

Comment: Not in my chrome